# Tap Action not working when Color is clear SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

my `tapAction` is not recognizing a tap when my `foregroundColor` is `clear`. When i remove the color it works fine.

That's my code:

```
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
        .frame(width: showMenu ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : 0)
        .tapAction {
            self.showMenu.toggle()
        }
    
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
        .shadow(radius: 5, y: 2)
        .padding(.trailing, 50)
        .frame(width: showMenu ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : 0)
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

Comment: Modifiers matter - along with the *order* of them, *and* the view they are attached to. Just to be, um, clear (sorry for the play on words)... can you **change** the color to something beside `.clear1` and verify that that works? (There's a difference between "removing" the color or more specifically *removing* the **modifier** and *blaming* it on the color choice.)

Comment: @dfd Removing the modifier or changing the color has the effect that the tapAction is getting calles

Comment: @dfd but i want the color to be clear

Comment: I understand. My questions on things to try were related to seeing if `Color.clear` really *is* the issue or if it's something else. And you comment read (to me) as though it's *not* something else. Check out this link - I know it's about `Button` but it's also showing how modifiers can behave different than expected depending on how you apply them. Hope it helps. https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/09/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/

Comment: `Color.clear` is the issue here! With any other `Color.` it is  working as expected

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The accurate way is to use `.contentShape(Rectangle())` on the view.
Described in this tutorial:

[control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape) by Paul Hudson @twostraws

```
VStack {
    Image("Some Image").resizable().frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    Spacer().frame(height: 50)
    Text("Some Text")
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture {
    print("Do Something")
}
```

[how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475258/swiftui-how-to-make-entire-shape-recognize-gestures-when-stroked) stackoverflow

Comment: Please add details in your answer as links might expire after a while. You should do it for future readers.

Comment: Edited with comment

Comment: No idea why this answer has not been marked as the correct answer. Pretty simple and to the point.

Comment: This does not work in at least one case (i.e. mine). I have a SpriteKit view I am trying to get to respond to a click. This answer did not work in that scenario.

Answer (score 25):

### UPDATE

[51N4’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58507379/77567) is better and you should do that.

### ORIGINAL

I have also discovered that a shape filled with `Color.clear` does not generate a tappable area.

Here are two workarounds:

1. Use `Color.black.opacity(0.0001)` (even on 10-bits-per-channel displays). This generates a color that is so transparent that it should have no effect on your appearance, and generates a tappable area that fills its frame. I don't know if SwiftUI is smart enough to skip rendering the color, so I don't know if it has any performance impact.
2. Use a `GeometryReader` to get the frame size, and then use the `contentShape` to generate the tappable area:

   ```
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.clear.contentShape(Path(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: proxy.size)))
    }
   ```

Comment: Worked when trying to make an entire SwiftUI view containing a SpiteKit view respond to clicks (on Mac OS). The only approach that did work in response to this question.

Comment: There seems to be a threshold now on transparency, that or maybe dragGesture is different. I'm using this trick to swipe on top of a scrollView on screen edge but it doesn't work with opacity below 0.01

Answer (score 12):

Here is the component

```
struct InvisibleButton: View {

    let action: (() -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            action?()
        }
    }
}
```

usage: Put your view and InbisibleButton in ZStack

```
ZStack {
     **yourView()**
     InvisibleButton {
        print("Invisible button tapped")
     }
}
```

you also can make a modifier to simplify usage:

```
struct InvisibleButtonModifier: ViewModifier {

    let action: (() -> Void)?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            InvisibleButton(action: action)
        }

    }
}


     **yourView()**
     .modifier(InvisibleButtonModifier {
        print("Invisible button tapped")
      })
```

However, if your SwiftUI View has a UIKit view as a subview under, you will have to set Color.gray.opacity(0.0001) in order to UIView's touches be ignored

Answer (score 1):

In my case a View that didn't trigger onTapGesture:

```
struct MainView: View {
  var action: () -> Void

  var body: some View {
    NotTappableView()
      .contentShape(Rectangle())
      .onTapGesture(
        action()
      )
  }
}
```

I solved this way:

```
struct MainView: View {
  var action: () -> Void

  var body: some View {
    NotTappableView()
      .overlay(
        Color.clear
          .contentShape(Rectangle())
          .onTapGesture {
             action()
          }
      )
  }
}
```

This made whole untappable view now tappable.